# array of substrings in array of strings

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, substring

I have two array of strings. Strings in one array might be the subset of string in other array. I need to find out which all strings in one array are the substrings of strings in the other array

Example:

```
arr1 = ["firestorm", "peanut", "earthworm"]
arr2 = ["fire", "tree", "worm", "rest"]
```

result:

```
res = ["fire","worm", "rest"]
```

My solution is mentioned below. But it takes a lot of time. I have to process Thousands of words.

Solution:

```
res =[]
arr1.each do |word1|
  arr2.each do |word2|
   if word1.include? word2
     res << word2
   end
  end
end
```

Please suggest me the faster way to to do this

Comment: If you have a solution, please include that in your question. There's no point in us trying to re-invent what you've already done, we can build on your existing work.

Comment: Suppose `arr1 = ['ab']` and `arr2 = ['b', 'a']`. What is the desired return value and why?

Comment: ruby is obviously not good at something like this. you should consider full-text search feature in redis. https://github.com/vruizext/redisearch-rb

Comment: The word "subset" implies that you are mentioning about `arr1` being a subset of `arr2`. Are you actually trying to mean "substring"?

Comment: am i missing something? why the negative votes?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunely we don't know your solution.

But Array takes up more memory space than String. So you can convert it.

```
arr1 = ["firestorm", "peanut", "earthworm"]
arr2 = ["fire", "tree", "worm", "rest"]

arr1 = arr1.join(',')
```

And then

```
res = arr2.select { |word| arr1.include?(word) } #=> ["fire", "worm", "rest"]
```

or

```
res = arr2.select { |word| arr1.match?(word) } #=> ["fire", "worm", "rest"]
```

or

```
res = arr2.select { |word| arr1.match(word) } #=> ["fire", "worm", "rest"]
```

Comment: Why do you need string interpolation in the second way?

Answer (score 1):

Due to overlapping terms you need to brute-force this as far as I can tell:

```
def matched(find, list)
  list.flat_map { |e| find.flat_map { |f| e.scan(f) } }.uniq
end
```

In practice:

```
matched(%w[ fire tree worm rest ], %w[ firestorm peanut earthworm ])
# => ["fire", "rest", "worm"]
```

Where here `%w` is used as a quicker way of expressing lists.

Here's an approximation using `scan` and `flat_map`:

```
def matched(find, list)
  rx = Regexp.union(find)

  list.flat_map { |e| e.scan(rx) }.uniq
end
```

Where using `Rexexp.union` you can make a regular expression that runs fairly quickly compared to individual tests.

Where it isn't as accurate:

```
matched(%w[ fire tree worm rest ], %w[ firestorm peanut earthworm ])
# => ["fire", "worm"]
```