# Compare two ruby arrays and return similar items

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays:

```
array1 = ["hello friend", "goodbye enemy", "yolo", "jello"]
array2 = ["ello", "random"]
```

I need to write a method that returns an array of the elements in array1 that include in a string item any of the items in array2.  So the method should return:

```
["hello friend", "jello"]
```

I've tried `array1.reject{|i| array1.include? array2}` but it just returns array1. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array of substrings in array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316267/array-of-substrings-in-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but missing some fundamentals.

1. #reject selects those elements which do *not* satisfy the block condition
2. Your block condition is testing if an element of array1 matches the entire array2 array - since a string and array will never match, all elements of array1 fail the test, and are thus returned.

Unrolling it, you have these tests:

```
"hello friend" == ["ello", "random"] # => false
"goodbye enemy" == ["ello", "random"] # => false
# etc
```

Assuming you want all elements from array1 for which any element in array2 is a substring:

```
array1.select do |i|
  array2.any? {|j| i.include?(j) }
end
```

This means "select all elements from array1 for which any element in array2 is a substring of the array1 element".

Unrolled, this gives you the following tests:

```
"hello friend".include?("ello") # => true
"hello friend".include?("random") # => false
"goodbye enemy".include?("ello") # => false
"goodbye enemy".include?("random") # => false
# etc
```

`#any?` returns true if any element in the Enumerable matches the block condition, so unrolled:

```
["ello", "random"].any? {|i| "hello friend".include?(i) } # => true
["ello", "random"].any? {|i| "goodbye enemy".include?(i) } # => false
```

Since `#select` returns those elements for which the block condition is true, "hello friend" would be returned, while "goodbye enemy" would not.

Answer (score 2):

```
array1 = ["hello friend", "goodbye enemy", "yolo", "jello", "Randomize"]
array2 = ["ello", "random"]

r = Regexp.new(Regexp.union(array2).source, 'i')
  #=> /ello|random/i  
array1.grep(r)
  #=> ["hello friend", "jello", "Randomize"]
```

See [Regexp::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-new), [Regexp::union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union), [Regexp#source](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-i-source) and [Enumerable#grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep).

Comment: Could run into problems if `array2` contains meta characters. Shame that `Regexp.union` doesn't accept options so you're forced to do things like `Regexp.new(Regexp.union(array).source, 'i')` or `/#{array.map { |s| Regexp.escape(s) }.join('|')}/i` to properly escape possible meta characters.